# When we entered the Starbucks shop,app icon will present on the home lock screen in iPhone without app in device?

Tags: ios, iphone, geolocation, app-store

When we entered the Starbucks shop,app icon will present on the home lock screen in iPhone when app not installed in device, If i tap the app icon it will redirect to the App store ask to download the app, I want to implement same thing in my app how it is possible please give any suggestions?
 Note:I used Geo-location in app

Answer (score -1):

You can give your application location awareness by using iBeacons:

> Give your iOS apps the ability to determine its proximity to iBeacon-enabled hardware with Core Location APIs.

https://developer.apple.com/ibeacon/

There are example projects available.

Comment: Please read the question before you post an answer. The OP clearly stated that, he didn't installed the app and it is showing the icon in launch screen. The answer you provided will work if and only if the app is already installed to the device.